# MQL4: Execute function if x is more than y

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex

Using `MQL4`, how can I execute a **`BUY`** order (seen below)
if one variable **`x`** has a value of 1
and another variable **`y`** has a value of 3?

I need it to work like this:

Variable `x = 1`

Variable `y = 3`

So if `x` is `MORE THAN y`, execute this script:

```
extern int TakeProfit = 10;
extern int StopLoss = 10;

void OnStart()
  {
   double TakeProfitLevel;
   double StopLossLevel; 

   TakeProfitLevel = Bid + TakeProfit*Point;
   StopLossLevel = Bid - StopLoss*Point;

   Alert("TakeProfitLevel = ", TakeProfitLevel);
   Alert("StopLossLevel = ", StopLossLevel);

   OrderSend("USDCAD", OP_BUY, 1.0, Ask, 10, StopLossLevel, TakeProfitLevel, "first order");

 }
```

And if `x` is `LESS THAN y`, execute this `SELL` script:

```
extern int TakeProfit = 10;
extern int StopLoss = 10;

void OnStart()
{
double TakeProfitLevel;
double StopLossLevel; 

TakeProfitLevel = Bid + TakeProfit*Point;
StopLossLevel = Bid - StopLoss*Point;

Alert("TakeProfitLevel = ", TakeProfitLevel);
Alert("StopLossLevel = ", StopLossLevel);

OrderSend("USDCAD", OP_SELL, 1.0, Ask, 10, StopLossLevel, TakeProfitLevel, "first order");

}
```

I'm struggling to find the `MQL4` code which establishes variables which can then be compared against each other e.g. `x > y` and vice versa, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### So, on the variables:

`MQL4` used to be a compiled, static typed language.

So the source-code contains all prior declarations, so as to allow the compiler to assume, what the heck the variable has as it's type ( and internal representation ).

```
int             ii = 0;
double       coeff = 1.23456789;
color  anMQL_color = 0x224466;             // could be stated as {int|hex|literals||colornames}
datetime  aTimeNOW = D'2016.08.23';
string    aLastMSG = "[ALARM] This TracePoint shall never be executed";
```

Recent `MQL4` language redesigns into a *New*-`MQL4.56789` have brought both a few new types ( i.e. `struct`-s )

The basic data types are:

·integers (`char, short, int, long, uchar, ushort, uint, ulong`);

·logical (`bool`);

·literals (`ushort`);

·strings (`string`); ( but are `struct` internally **(!!)**, so be carefull in DLL API )

·floating-point numbers (`double, float`);

·color (`color`);

·date and time (`datetime`);

·enumerations (`enum`).

Complex data types are:

·`struct`;

·`class`-es.

New language has also introduced a type casting, like this one:

```
int aFactoredNUMBER = EMPTY;                             // declaration + initial value assignment
    aFactoredNUMBER = (int) ( coeff * 3.1412592653598 ); // operation with a resulting value type casting into (int)
```

### So how about the `x > y` ?

let me sketch a few SLOCs:

```
double x = 1,
       y = 3;
...
..
.

if (  x > y ) { ... ;
                OrderSend( , OP_BUY,  ... );
                return;
                }

if (  x < y ) { ... ;                            // THIS
                OrderSend( , OP_SELL, ... );     // COULD BE A CALL TO FUN( { OP_BUY | OP_SELL } )
                return;
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's exactly what I was looking to do. Do you think it would be possible to set variable y to read an economic news announcement? I know this is a whole other topic entirely, but is it possible? I'd like to manually enter variable x as an economic announcement forecast, and then compare it to variable y which fetches the actual figure. I know issues will arise from latency etc, but is it possible to achieve nonetheless?

Comment: You are welcome, p.luck. **Feel free to ask more, `MQL4` related or not, questions**, this is what StackOverflow is being used to.